# Update ImageField on change of TextInput

Tags: admin-on-rest

Given a `SimpleForm`:

```
<SimpleForm>
    <TextInput source="imageUrl" label="Image URL" />
    <ImageField source="imageUrl" label="Image" />
</SimpleForm>
```

I'd like to have the `ImageField` update as the user types in the `TextInput`.  Is this somehow possible out of the box, or will I have to wire it up myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably build a custom input like the one we built for image upload. Instead of the file input, just use a text input and handle the image visualization inside it.