# Update DateInput based on value of another DateInput

Tags: admin-on-rest

Given two `DateInput` elements, one for 'start date' and another for 'end date', is there a way to have the second update so that it is no earlier than the first, whenever the first changes?

I suspect this will have a similar answer as one of my earlier questions ([Update ImageField on change of TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439028/update-imagefield-on-change-of-textinput)), but wanted to check.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write logic and components for this.

Use MUI datepickers within a stateful component and store the selected date in state.

Display the date stored in component state by passing the value prop to the MUI component.